# Git HEAD file location in remote repository

Tags: git

I'm working on a Git project and had a question about HEAD.

In our remote Git repository, I see the file

```
git_repo_home/HEAD
```

and another file

```
git_repo_home/refs/heads/HEAD
```

The content of the former file is  `refs/heads/master`  which looks ok because 
we want `HEAD` pointing at `master`.

However, should the latter file exist?  I had thought only branches
should exist in /refs/heads and `HEAD` isn't a branch right?  I'm wondering
if we erroneously created a `HEAD` branch.  The contents of this file is an SHA hash.

Answer (score 1):

Do  a `git branch -a` and see if you are seeing `HEAD` as one of the branches. You must have created one, like you mentioned. You can delete it.